# How can animate between array filter methods with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im currently building my personal Portfolio and I have an array of objects containing multiple projects, each one of the project object contain a property called category, which can have a value of 'Visual' or 'Complexity'.

My plan is to add two buttons, one for each category, but I would like to animate between the category changes, a simple fade out and fade in would be nice, any idea how can I do this ?

I tried using React Transition Group for this, but didn't manage to figure it out.

The first Component is the ProjectUl, this component will receive a filter prop, which is basically a string indicating which category should the filter method use.

```js
const projects = [
  {
    name: "Limitless",
    category: "visual",
    dash: "- Landing Page",
    img: imgList.limitless,
    gif: imgList.limitlessGif,
  },
  {
    name: "Spacejet",
    category: "complexity visual",
    dash: "- Landing Page / API Project; ",
    img: imgList.spacejet,
  },
];

export const ProjectsUl: FC<IProps> = ({ filter }) => {
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState<IProject[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredProjects = projects.filter((i) => i.category.includes(filter));
    setFiltered(filteredProjects);
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <ProjectsUlStyle>
      {filtered.map((i) => (
        <ProjectsLi filtered={i} />
      ))}
    </ProjectsUlStyle>
  );
};
```

Then, inside the ProjectsUl there will be the ProjectsLi, which are the list of projects, here is the code for the ProjectsLi

```js
export const ProjectsLi: FC<any> = ({ filtered }) => {
  return (
    <LiStyle>
      <img src={filtered.img} />
      <div>
        <span className="dash">{filtered.dash}</span>
        <header>
          <h1>{filtered.name}</h1>
          <FAicons.FaGithub />
          <FAicons.FaCode />
        </header>
      </div>
    </LiStyle>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Just added the code in case someone can help me